# Code Sign error - XCode 4.5 - iOS 6

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, xcode4.5

I updated XCode to v. 4.5 and now when I try to Run an app I get the error: `Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains` I don't use Apple Developer program for 99$.

**What's wrong?**

It happened just after the update. I searched a lot of answers on stackoverflow but no one helped me.

Comment: but do you have any other Developer license provided by somebody else? Are you trying to run it in the simulator or in a device?

Comment: OMG Thanks a lot!!! I saw that XCode asking me what a device it needs to use for Run but I didn't know why it thought so... because I use simulator. :) I changed from iOS Device to Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

You *have to* use the Apple Developer Program if you want to run your app from Xcode on your non-jailbroken iOS device.

If you are trying to run the app in the Simulator, you have to select it from the drop down list at the top left corner in Xcode. And make sure (in the Build Settings) that you don't code sign.